# add tab to rows that start with a numeric value

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a text-file on a linux server and would like to add one tab at the beginning of each line that start with a numeric value and not to rows that do not have numeric value at the beginning.

I know how to add a tab, but not how to specify the rule about numeric at the beginning.

Input:

```
String1
String2
103_String
2424_String
```

Desired output:

```
String1
String2
       103_String
       2424_String
```

Comment: Using gnu-sed: `sed -i 's/^[0-9]/\t&/' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, sed is more appropriate than awk here:

```
sed '/^[0-9]/s/^/    /'
```

Some sed allow you to use `\t` rather than an explicit tab, but the latter is more portable.  If you are using those sed, you can do:

```
sed '/^[0-9]/s/^/\t/'
```

Or you could do:

```
sed "/^[0-9]/s/^/$(printf \\t)/"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{printf "\t"} 1' file.txt
```

The idea here is that if the line starts with a number (`^[0-9]`), then print a tab (`\t`). Additionally, print every line (`1`).